# why Math.max.apply doesn't care the first parameter

Tags: javascript, math

```
function smallest(array){
  return Math.min.apply(Math, array);
}
```

It specifies the context as being the `Math` object. This isn’t necessary (the min() and max() methods will continue to work regardless of what’s passed in as the context.

Why does it work even though passed like `undefined`?
Why isn't it necessary to pass `Math`?

Comment: Because `Math.min` only takes `arguments` as parameters, `this` doesn't matter; it's not operating on array like `[1,2,3].min()` for example.

Comment: You could have read the docs for [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument to `apply` will be bound to `this` when the function executes.<sup>1</sup> If the function does not reference `this` (including indirectly, through functions it might call), then it doesn't matter what `this` is. It happens that `Math.min` makes no use of `this` when it executes.

<sup>1</sup> This is almost accurate. From [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), regarding the first argument:

> Note that this may not be the actual value seen by the method: if the method is a function in non-strict mode code, null and undefined will be replaced with the global object, and primitive values will be boxed.